# Parenting.SE is great and all but

Tags: discussion

[image: Stats don't lie]

...the stats don't lie. And they haven't for the past 2283+ days since we've gone beta. I was excited for Parenting.SE because it was about the time I started having lots of questions about my daughter (age 1-2) and now she's 6. We were beta then, we're still beta.

Are we ever going to admit that Parenting.SE will never meet the standards required? Or has this been addressed and I just haven't scrolled far enough?

### Oh yea! My question

Has there been a status update on this or any news on what might come of this site?

Comment: I don't disagree (at all), but I'm not sure I understand the point of the question :)

Comment: @Erica oh yea! Questions! Those usually help (updated)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a more general shift in policy across the entire Stack Exchange network. Length of time in beta is not an issue, and sites can progress as they need to.

Have a read of [Graduation, site closure, and a clearer outlook on the health of SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites) and the associated questions, to see the general approach taken. So don't panic.

That said, it would be nice to get our QPD up...

Comment: I don't meant to be negative, but I'm pretty sure that's never going to happen. And that's just the nature of asking parenting questions. There's a limited set of qualities that keeps questions about parenting objective rather than subjective. Usually they take a long time to write and a long time to answer. We have a good community here and we luck out because we have a huge pool of new parents in the IT community who discovered SO or ServerFault first and then stumbled upon Parenting (like me). I just don't think it's going to happen.

Comment: It's not really negative, as it doesn't actually matter. Graduation isn't as big a deal as it used to be, and isn't necessary.

Comment: Good enough for me